# Change suggested commands in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

When I start to type a command in TeXstudio, I like the fact that a full list of commands comes up; but I was wondering if there was a way to change the order from alphabetical to some other order so that I can autocomplete some of the more common commands I use faster.  If not that; is there a way for the "most used" pane to open automatically instead of the "typical" one?

Comment: in the options → completion you can select your preferred commands set (all, typical, most frequently used). This list will still be alphabetical but might be better suited for you if you change to 'most frequently used'. I am not aware of an option to change the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second idea can be enabled in the preferences. Go to the `Completion`-tab, there is a drop-down menu, where you can select which set should be opened by default.

[image]