# Remove commands from "most used commands" in command completion in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

This question is related to this question: [change-suggested-commands-in-texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297678/change-suggested-commands-in-texstudio) 
and this question: [can-suggested-commands-be-removed-from-texstudios-autocomplete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245603/can-suggested-commands-be-removed-from-texstudios-autocomplete)

I have changed my completion commands to show the most used, but now I have a command `\part*{title}` in this list, which I don't use often and it's blocking `\partial` from showing up first.

Is there a way to remove the `\part*{title}` command from my *most used commands* - list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored in the file `wordCount.usage` in the [settings directory](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored). However, it's a binary format and we currently do not provide methods to remove single words. You can only delete the complete file.